# What would be the xpath file I can create for the following href: <a href="/8000j0000000XlzAAE" id="8000j0000000XlzAAE" target="_blank">00730073</a>?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, href

I'm new to using xpath statements.  Using the following href:

```
<a href="/8000j0000000XlzAAE" id="8000j0000000XlzAAE" target="_blank">00730073</a>
```

How would I write the xpath?

I'm using Xpath Helper and when I use the following xpath:

```
//a[contains(@href,'8000')]
```

Its returning the incorrect results.  I was expecting '00730073', but I'm getting '00730075'

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'level 1')]")).Click();
By the way, you can find element by the href attribute using CssSelector

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='level 1']")).Click();

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar The HTML posted doesn't contain "level 1" so neither of those locators will work.

Comment: It has an ID, why not just use that?

Comment: As id and href seems to have value at run time, so identifying link based on it's text will be better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using ID as your locator is usually your safest bet, since it is always going to be a unique match.

```
//a[@id="8000j0000000XlzAAE"]
```

But you could also access it by the text (hyperlink):

```
//a[text()="00730073"];
```

or finally, you could access it by the href itself:

```
//a[@href="/8000j0000000XlzAAE"]
```

The text and href are more likely to change over time, and thus break your script, so that's another reason to use ID whenever available.  That can change too, but it rarely does.

Comment: Thanks.  That's part of my challenge.  When I used //a[text()="00730073"]; a NULL value was returned.  Is there a way that I can create a generic xpath to pull 00730073?

Comment: Are you assigning it to a WebElement?  Try wrapping the line in a try/catch block and see if it raises a NoSuchElementException.  So me the code you are using to access the element.  Assuming your WebDriver is called "driver" it should be something like WebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[text()='00730073']");  Notice that inside the code you'd need to change the double quotes in my original example to single quotes.  Also, there are a variety of reasons it might not find it, even if the XPath is valid - it might be inside an IFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

Using text of link

"//a[contains(.,'00730073')]";

I hope it will help you.